# Should I seperate model classes or have them as a single unit?

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, architecture

My game logic model consists of multiple connected classes. There are `Board`, `Cell`, `Character`, etc. `Character` can be placed (and moved) in `Cell` (1-1 rel).

There are two approaches:

1. Make each class of model implement interfaces so that they can be mocked and each class can be tested independently. It forces me to make implementation of each class to not rely on another. But in practice it's hard to avoid `Board` knowing about `Cells` too much and `Characters` knowing how `Cell` storing mechanism works. I have a `Character.Cell` and `Cell.CurrentCharacter` properties. In order for setters to work correctly (not go recursively) they should rely on each others implementation. It feels like the model logic should be considered as a single unit.
2. Make all public members to return interfaces but use exact classes inside (can involve some downcasting). The cons here are such that I should test the whole model as a single and can't use mocking to test different parts independently. Also there is no sense to use dependency injection inside model, only to get another full model implementation from controller.

So what to do?

**UPDATE**

You can propose other options.

Comment: Can you explain in more details why each class in your model needs to know some of the other classes implementations?

Comment: @YacoubMassad not each and this is more about knowing *behavior*. `Character` knows that when it sets `Cell.CurrentCharacter` the Cell makes a recursive call back to `Character.Cell` setter (to ensure consistency) so it should implement its side correctly to not go for `Cell.CurrentCharacter` again.

Comment: When does Character decide to set Cell.CurrentCharacter? When Character.Cell setter is invoked? Who invokes Character.Cell in the first place? The Board class? Who consumes these classes (Board, Cell, and Character)? Can you make all access to such classes go though the Board class (as in the [aggregate pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html))  ?

Comment: @YacoubMassad `Board` moves things each game step. Upper-level uses only getters of `Cell` and `CurrentCharacter`. No, I can't route all access through `Board`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad actually I thought about making model seperated from step (turn) logic and only ensure consistency in model code. So there should be 2 users (player and turn runner) which should take different interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are these the only 2 options?

If you intend to have different versions/types of the classes then interfaces/abstract base classes are a good option to enforce shared behaviour and generalize many operations. However the idea of building the classes independently without knowledge of each other is ridiculous.
It is always a good idea to separate class storage/behaviour to the class/layer it belongs. E.g. no business logic code in the data layer, etc. but the classes need to know about each other in order to function properly. If you make everything independent and based on interfaces you run the risk of over generalizing the application and reducing your efficiency.
Basically if you think you would need to ever downcast the incoming objects to more than one type it's a good idea to look at the design and see if you are gaining anything for the performance loss and nasty casting code you are about to write. If you will be required to handle every type of downcast object you have not gained anything and using polymorphism and a base class is a much better way to go.

Using interfaces does not eliminate your trouble in testing. You will still have to instantiate some version of the objects to test most of the functions on the cell/board anyway. Which for full regression testing will require you test each character's interaction with both.

Don't get me wrong, your character class should most likely have a base class or have an interface. All characters will (I'm sure) share many actions and can benefit from this design. E.g. Moving a character on the board is a fairly generic operation and can be made independent of the character except for a few pieces of information (such as how the character moves, if they are allowed to move, etc.) which should be part of said base class/interface.

When it is reasonable, design classes independently so that they can be tested on their own, but do not use testing as a reason to write bad code. Simple stubs or basic testing instances can be created to help with component testing and takes far less time and effort than fixing unnecessarily complex code.
Interfaces have a purpose, but if you will not be treating 2 classes the same... that is not it.

*Using MVC gives you a leg up on testing as well. If done correctly you should be able to swap out any of the layers to ease your testing of a single layer.

Comment: "Why are these the only 2 options?", I updated the question, I can accept another option too if it's viable.

Comment: In 2nd option I'm not going to downcast to different types, just to one which belongs to the model. This can be necessary only for public method parameters (upper-level uses only interfaces of model classes). The purpose for that is accessing non-published via interface methods which are specific for and required for model internal operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just want to clarify: you think I should use 2nd option, correct?

Comment: I don't think either is correct. Interfaces are meant to allow 2 or more classes be treated as the same. E.g. it enforces commonality between them and allows generic usage. If you only intend to downcast and use the derived type the code doesn't gain anything. You still have to include derived type into the other class which doesn't avoid one class 'knowing' about another. All you gain is generic parameters, but from the sound of it you don't intend to use the generic types.